# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' using .env

Tags: php, mysql, environment-variables

I created a .env file to store my connection variables, when I get the values ​​of these variables on a page without connection all values ​​appear but when I try to access the database, access is denied. The credentials are correct when I connect to the data base with them directly in the code (without the .env) it works normaly. Can anyone tell me where the error is?

the .env file:
I already tried to put the ip on the host and put it without quotes

```
BANCO_HOST="localhost"
BANCO_NOME="orcamento01"
BANCO_USUARIO="root"
BANCO_SENHA= ""
```

The connection file:

```
 try {
            $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . getenv('BANCO_HOST') . ';dbname=' .  getenv('BANCO_NOME'),
            getenv('BANCO_USUARIO'),
            getenv('BANCO_SENHA') );

            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            return $conn;
        } catch (\PDOException $erro) {
            echo $erro->getMessage();
        }
```

The error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: What is loading the `.env` file into the environment to make those values available? The `.env` file sounds like a Laravel convention, but not sure what you're using. Try doing a simple `echo getenv('BANCO_HOST'); die();` before the `$conn =` statement to see if that is outputting what you expect.

Comment: I'm not using a framework, it didn't show anything on the output, it just show when I do a print_r($_ENV); on the index.php file

Comment: If it appears with the `print_r`, then maybe try with: `$_ENV['BANCO_HOST']` instead of `getenv`.

Comment: I change it and now it's showing: : Undefined index: BANCO_HOST

Comment: Then how/where was the `print_r` used?

Comment: on the index.php, not the same file as the connection file

Comment: Did not get an answer to the original question: What is loading the `.env` file into the environment to make those values available? The setup of how it's only working from the index.php is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience, I just found the error, I was calling the routers before the dotenv so it was on the bottom of the page.

Comment: No problem, glad you found the trouble. :-)

Answer (score 0):

.env files don't load automatically. Frameworks like Laravel will load it for you, but if you don't use framework - you need to load it manually.
The simple solution may be like this:

```
 $envFile = __DIR__ . '/.env';
 if (is_file($envFile)) {
   foreach (parse_ini_file($envFile) as $key => $value) {
     $_ENV[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

But it's very naive solution, frameworks made it many more better